# Limit of $(\arcsin x)^{\tan x}$ as $x$ tends to zero from the right

Tags: limits

I came across an interesting limit I could not solve:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0^{+}}\left[\arcsin\left(x\right)\right]^{\tan\left(x\right)}
$$

Given we have not proven l'Hôpital's rule yet, I have to solve it without it. Also, I would rather not use advanced methods such as the taylor series (which yield $x^x$ here).

Squeeze theorem does not (easily?) really help here, nor does the exponent function as far as I see it:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}(\arcsin x)^{\tan\,x} = 
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} e^{{\tan(x)}\ln(\arcsin x)}
$$
Here again the exponent is an undefined term $(0 \cdot +\infty)$. Unlike all limits I practiced on however, this logarithm does not tend to $1$, so I don't really see how it cancels out.

Is there an easy solution I am missing?

Comment: When $x$ is close to $0$, both $\arcsin x$ and $\tan x$ are 'equal' to $x$, so you get $x^x$. (This is essentially the first order Taylor approximation.)

Comment: The limit should be $1$.

Comment: @Ragnar fair enough to be an intuition, I think am expected to give a more elaborate proof however.

Comment: $\large\arcsin\left(x\right)$ and $\large\tan\left(x\right)$  $\large\sim x$ when $\large x \sim 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim \limits_{x\to0^{+}}(\arcsin(x))^{\tan(x)}=\lim \limits_{x\to0^{+}}e^{\large{\tan(x)\ln(\arcsin(x))}}$$
therefore,
$\tan(x)\ln(\arcsin(x))=\tan(x)\ln\left[x(1+\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}-1)\right]=$
$$\tan(x)\ln(x)+\tan(x)\frac{\ln(1+\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}-1)}{\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}-1} \left (\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x} -1\right)$$ 
the second addend goes to zero as $x \rightarrow 0^{+}$, because 
$(\frac{\arcsin(x)}{x}-1)$ and $\tan(x)$ $\rightarrow 0^{+}$ as $x \rightarrow 0^{+}$ while the central factor tends to 1.
The first addend is equal to
$x\ln(x)\frac{\tan(x)}{x}$ which tends to zero. 
The whole exponent tends to zero, therefore 
$$\lim \limits_{x\to0^{+}}e^{\large{\tan(x)\ln(\arcsin(x))}}=e^0=1$$

Comment: Oh this is so awesome. Thank you. Love it!

Comment: you're welcome!

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align} \lim \limits_{x\to0^{+}}(\arcsin(x))^{\tan(x)}&=\lim \limits_{x\to0^{+}}e^{\large{\tan(x)\ln(\arcsin(x))}}\\
=e^{\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\tan(x)}{x}(\arcsin(x)\ln(\arcsin(x)))\frac{x}{\arcsin(x)}
}=1\end{align}$$

Notice that $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\arcsin(x)\ln(\arcsin(x))=-\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\ln(\frac{1}{\arcsin(x)})}{{\frac{1}{\arcsin(x)}}}=-\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{\ln(u)}{u}$

We demonstrate this limit by noticing: $0\le\frac{\ln(u)}{u}=\frac{1}{u}\int_{1}^{u}\frac{1}{t}dt\le\frac{1}{u}\int_{1}^{u}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}dt=\frac{2(\sqrt{u}-1)}{u}=2(\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}-\frac{1}{u})$

for $u$ sufficiently large. So the limit is $0$.

$\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{x}{\arcsin(x)}=\frac{1}{\frac{d(\arcsin(x))}{dx}}|_{x=0^{+}}=\sqrt{1-x^{2}}|_{x=0^{+}}=1$.

Also $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\tan(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\frac{1}{\cos(x)}=1$.

Comment: Why would the log cancel out? As far as I remember $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\log(x+1)}{x} = 1$, but this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Sorry I was in the middle of making corrections.

Comment: Bear with me for a second here please: $(1 + \arcsin(x) - 1) \rightarrow 0 \ne 1$, so why did the log cancel out? Are you using the limit I wrote in the comment above? Because $\lim_{x\to 0} \, \frac{\log \left(\arcsin(x)\right)}{\arcsin(x)}=-\infty$

Comment: I am using the limit that you wrote in your comment where $x$ will be denoted by $\arcsin(x)-1$.

Comment: However, if $s = \arcsin(x)-1 \wedge x\rightarrow 0 \Rightarrow s \rightarrow -1$, because $\arcsin(0)=0$, right? Meaning the whole argument of the log tends to $0$, not $1$, thus the partial limit in the topmost comment above does not seem applicable.

Comment: I just came back here for this very reason... It seems your argument is wrong. :-(

Comment: I have been made aware I'm just thinking of how to fix it right now. My apologies.

Comment: Seems valid now. In the last part I will rather use $\lim_{+\infty} \frac{\ln u}{u} = \ln \lim_{+\infty} n^{1/n} = \ln 1 = 0$ rather than the integral however, taking the last limit axiomatic as I have proven that before. Thanks :)

Comment: Your welcome. Sorry for the earlier mistake. If you catch any more I am more than happy to correct it.

Comment: ...or just replace *u* with $e^t$...

Comment: I'm sorry, I just had to pick the other answer as it's more elegant. I do really appreciate the effort though, sir. I have learned a lot through our discussion.

Comment: No problem happy to help. Glad you have learned through the discussion.